# Can't run programs on my mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I've been programming on windows for about three months now and when my computer finally died I bought a mac. I'm really happy with it except I can't figure out how to run my c++ programs.

On windows it would open up in command prompt so I figured it would do the same thing except with terminal.

After I write my programs (in Xcode) I can compile them and it'll tell me if there are syntax errors but the run and run related buttons are all Grey and unusable.

It's incredibly annoying that I can't see how the program that I put 4 hours into runs and even more annoying that I don't know if I've made a runtime error. Someone please help.

Thank you very much, James

Comment: If there are syntax errors, you need to fix those - until you do, there won't be anything *to* run, because your program failed to compile.

Comment: Open up Terminal. "cd" to the directory. Try running the output file (usually defaults to a.out) using "./a.out" or whatever the name of the file is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to write a program that you interact with on the command line, you want to create a "Command Line Tool" project, found under "Application" in the Mac OS X section of the New Project dialog. Choose "C++ stdc++" from the "Type" dropdown, as well. This will give you a main.cpp that should look familiar to you, with a "Hello, World!" sample.

Note that when you Run this program, it might appear to do nothing - You need to open the Console (from the Run menu, or shift+command+R) to see your output.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode deals in projects. If you're just opening the source file, there is no project. Create a project with the files in it and Xcode should let you run it.

Alternately, you can just use G++ on the command line to compile your files and run the resulting executable there.

Comment: Which project should I use? I've been making all my programs under the "STL C++ Library" under the "Framework & Library" category. Then it gives me a bunch of files and I just edit the .cp file.

Comment: @James Fargotson: That's for making a library, not a standalone program. You want to make a command-line tool like @spwert describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling from the terminal as stated above. The a.out file should be created, and should run as long as Xcode has been installed. It should work fine from the terminal, and point out any errors in the compiler's output.
To runs the a.out file, ensure you are in the files directory in terminal and type ./a.out